# Obtaining GPS periodically in Android

Tags: android, gps

OK there is a question about GPS in android. A couple of days I try to create code, which would every 20 seconds detect a location (longitude, latitude) and then it would send this info to a server. But this question is not about sending data.

I had couple of ideas and advices, I have read bunch or tutorials how to create picking up coordinates in a loop:

1. In `activity`, using `LocationListener`
2. `IntentService`

BUT:
Using `LocationListener`, it´s true that I can obtain coordinates with `onLocationChanged()` method, the problem is that it´s an `Activity`, so I assume that collecting coordinates would be stopped if the screen turned off OR somebody calls.

Using `IntentService` and `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider)` - this seems to be great, because it runs in it´s own thread, but in a loop (which has to be there, because we want to pick coordinates in intervals) this code doesn´t work:

```
      lat = location.getLatitude();
      lon = location.getLongitude();
```

It works only the first time, after that, the coordinates remain still the same (I´ve tried also re-declaring `LocationManager`, it changed nothing). It seems to me that obtaining coordinates is unnecessarily complicated.

MY QUESTION is: Am I missing something/Am I doing it wrong? Thanks for your help, I appreciate every useful advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) instead of an IntentService.  IntentServices quit immediately after finishing the code in `onHandleIntent()`, regardless of whether any callbacks have returned data yet.  Also creating a loop to repeatedly poll `getLastKnownLocation()` is a very inefficient way to fetch location updates, even on a separate thread.  A better approach is to pass a [LocationListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) to `requestLocationUpdates()`, freeing the CPU from the busywork of a blocking loop.

Be warned, Services are *not* run on their own Thread by default, you need to do this yourself.  I recommend using a [HandlerThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) since `requestLocationUpdates()` needs a Looper to properly function.

---

From [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)'s documentation:

> IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.

From [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#WhatIsAService)'s documenation:

> Most confusion about the Service class actually revolves around what it is *not*:
>
> - A Service is **not** a separate process. The Service object itself does not imply it is running in its own process; unless otherwise specified, it runs in the same process as the application it is part of.
> - A Service is **not** a thread. It is not a means itself to do work off of the main thread (to avoid Application Not Responding errors).

Answer (score 0):

I guess I don't quite understand what you're saying. As far as I can tell, neither the [Location Strategies](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) documentation nor the [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) documentation say anything about having to implement it as an activity. And as far as I understand it (and actually have used it), the LocationListener is asynchronous: it will from time to time provide you with new information as to your Location. It's up to you how you use it.

What I would do is: create a LocationListener at the start of the service and periodically check if its information has changed. The first document I linked to gives a pretty good explanation how to use it.